# gdaltranslate loop for compressing .tif

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I'm looking to do a batch file for running a loop to all the .tif images that I have in a folder. I´ve been trying to do this:

`for %%v in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -if Gtiff -of Gtiff -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -mask 4 -co alpha=no -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co TILED=YES %%v %~dp0comprimidos\%%v`

I´m new to GDAL in console so maybe I'm doing a big mistake and not noticing.

Comment: Stackoverflow could be a better forum for a Windows FOR loop question.

Comment: Yeah you are rigth, i´m trying to think do this in Python since is more developed. This is the forum i should ask? Or its StackOverflow again? Since OSGEO promp i think is similar

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Do you get errors?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and modified an [existing script](https://gist.github.com/percursoaleatorio/5293340)... it got quite complex, I apologize for that. But due to the complexity, it can now handle in-place compression, recursion to subdirectories and an optional output directory :)

I placed it as a file `compressTIFS.bat` in my C:\OSGeo4W folder. When opening the OSGeo4W Shell (which already "knows" GDAL, i.e. adds it to the PATH), I can directly access this script via: `compressTIFS.bat "X:\my_example\directory"`.

The contents of `compressTIFS.bat`:

```
@echo off
rem "compressTIFS.bat"
rem >> compressTIFS directory_input directory_output -r
rem Loop over folder with .tifs and compress files to new folder

rem DEPENDENCIES:
rem 1) GDAL - the command GDAL_TRANSLATE must be found on PATH
rem     this can be achieved by running this bat file within the OSGeo4W shell
rem     or manually adding GDAL to PATH

rem author: Hannes Horneber
rem v2023.04
rem based on this script: https://gist.github.com/percursoaleatorio/5293340

echo -------------------------
echo Start Batch TIF Compression
echo Processing directory: %1

if "%~1" == "" goto errorInput
if not exist "%1" goto errorDir

set inplace=false
if "%~2" == "" (
    echo Output dir not specified... compressing in place using temp files
    set inplace=true
) else (
    echo Output directory: "%~2"
    if not exist "%~2" (
        mkdir "%~2"
        echo Output dir doesn't exist ... created.
    )
)

set recurse=false
if "%~3" == "-r" (
    echo Recursive processing is enabled
    set recurse=true
)

echo -------------------------

rem define gdal command. can also be used for other commands (here we only compress)
set gdal_cmd=gdal_translate -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE"

if %recurse%==true (
  echo Processing directory recursively
  for /r "%1" %%i in (*.tif) do (
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "file=%%i"
    if "!file:~-4!" == ".tif" (
      set "folder=!file:%~1=!"
      set "fname=%%~ni"
      set "outdir=%~2!folder!"
      if not exist "!outdir!" mkdir "!outdir!"
      echo Processing %%i
      if %inplace%==true (
        %gdal_cmd% "%%i" "%%i_temp.tif"
        echo Deleting temp file and renaming.
        echo del "%%i"
        echo ren "%%i_temp.tif" "%%i"
        ren "%%i_temp.tif" "%%i"
      ) else (
        if exist "!outdir!\!fname!.tif" (
          echo WARNING Output file "!outdir!\!fname!.tif" already exists... skipping.
        ) else (
          %gdal_cmd% "%%i" "!outdir!\!fname!.tif"
        )
      )
      endlocal
    )
  )
) else (
  echo Processing directory non-recursively
  for %%i in ("%~1\*.tif") do (
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "fname=%%~ni"
    echo Processing %%i
    if %inplace%==true (
      %gdal_cmd% "%%i" "%~1\!fname!_temp.tif"
      echo Deleting temp file and renaming.
      del "%%i"
      echo ren "%~1\!fname!_temp.tif" "!fname!.tif"
      ren "%~1\!fname!_temp.tif" "!fname!.tif"
    ) else (
      if exist "%~2\!fname!.tif" (
        echo WARNING Output file "%~2\!fname!.tif" already exists... skipping.
      ) else (
        %gdal_cmd% "%%i" "%~2\!fname!.tif"
      )
    )
    endlocal
  )
)

goto :end

:errorDir
echo ERROR Input directory doesn't exist... exiting.
goto :end
:errorInput
echo ERROR Input directory isn't specified ... exiting.
goto :end
:end
echo -------------------------
```